# Team summoner icons

Tags: league-of-legends

One day after a finished normal game I spotted that one of the opposition summoners had a CLG-EU icon beside their name.How were they able to retain this icon when the championship event was over?

Comment: You mean, it was "CLG-EU summoner name" ?
Maybe that this person created an account with a summoner name coutaining the "CLG-EU"

Comment: I think it must be a bug. Because they were removed after the event was over :/

Comment: @Cindytroford I don't think you can include icons in your summoner name.

Comment: What was the summoner's name?

Comment: @Sadly Not ,the name didnt have CLG-EU.The name was 'Imagoodeep' and he was on north american servers.

Comment: @cindytroford nope

Comment: Are you sure? It shows up as CLG-EU on lolking, but in the actual client, it's Blue Melee Minion...

Comment: O.o oh um... havent checked the actual client yet where you search the name up,but it did appear as CLG-EU after the game on the stats.

Comment: probably just a bug, or if this game wasn't too long after the championships then they may have still had it before the icons were taken away

Comment: dam,wished they were deliberate so i could find a way to get myself one too xP

Answer (score 1):

This could be of two things:

1. Most likely it's because they never changed their summoner icon since the end of League of legends Season II. If you don't change it, it doesn't have anything to default to. Thus, it'll stay the same.
2. The obvious answer: bug/hacking.